# How to set image in center of different hight and width using html and css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to set all the images in center and five image in first row and rest of the images in second row in center. I tried the following code.

```
<section id="Section">
    <h1 class="sectionTitle text-center">Images</h1>
    <div class="row center" id="Logo">
      <!-- All logo from firestore -->
    </div>
</section>
```

I am using firestore here is my JavaScript code:

```
db.collection('images').orderBy('image').onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    //insertHtml("#main-content", response);
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {

       var brand = '<div class="column">'
                       + '<img src="images/'+ doc.data().image + '"></div>';
       $("#Logo").append(brand);
        
    });
});
```

here is my css code:

```
#Section .center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 80%;
}

#Section .row .column {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

#Section .row .column img{
  max-height: 115px;
  max-width: 210px;
}
```

There are 8/9 images, so first row works well, but 2nd row is not in center. I want to fix it. How can I do it ?
[image]

Comment: you can simply use a bootstrap template from:  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use display flex and change the flex-basis to 100/number of elements like so :

```css
#Section .center {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  justify-content : center;
  align-items : center;
  flex-wrap : wrap;
  column-gap : 15px;
  row-gap : 15px;
  width: 80%;
}

.logos {
  text-align : center;
  flex-basis : calc(20% - 15px);
  background-color : red;
]
```

```html
<section id="Section">
    <h1 class="sectionTitle text-center">Images</h1>
    <div class="row center" id="Logo">
      <div class="logos"> 1 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 2 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 3 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 4 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 5 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 6 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 7 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 8 </div>
      <div class="logos"> 9 </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

**For the alignment of all elements horizontally**

```
<div class="row justify-content-center" id="Logo">
<div class="col-md-*"> 1 logo </div> 
<div class="col-md-*"> 2 logo </div> 
<div class="col-md-*"> 3 logo </div> 
<div class="col-md-*"> 4 logo </div> 
<div class="col-md-*"> 5 logo </div> 
</div>

<div class="row justify-content-center" id="Logo">
<div class="col-md-4"> 1 logo </div> 
<div class="col-md-4"> 2 logo </div>
<div class="col-md-4"> 3 logo </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you need?

[example

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

img {
  width: 40px;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="" alt="1" />
  </div>
</div>
```